# WSO2: POX to SOAP - recommended approach?

Tags: wso2, esb

Simple question off the back of an unsuccessful attempt at the Feature's section of ESB certification: what is the recommended approach to support POX to SOAP transformation? As i recall there was a number of options listed based on the XSLT mediators & one as data mapper; i believe there naturally a number of ways to do this (a there always is) & i believe you could approach the problem using either data mapper or XSLT mediator but i struggle to differentiate which would be the default method that is correct?  Advice appreciated. . . Brad

Answer (score 0):

This answer if opinion based (I believe as the question is), feel free to comment if I misunderstood something.

> what is the recommended approach to support POX to SOAP transformation?

For POX to SOAP you need to do payload and protocol transformation

For the payload transformation, as you have already mentioned, you can use **payloadFactory, data mapper or XSLT**. All are doing their job good. Do yo really need to choose one and stick to that?

I'd say it depends on the **complexity of the transformed payload**. Use the right tool for the right job. Having extra artifacts (mapper or xslt) gives you more transformation capability, but the price is increased complexity you have to handle with versioning, migration, etc.. and performance requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I can say that you have to implement message transformation first.
In this case, plain old XML (POX) to SOAP.
It can be done with a Data Mapper
Finally, you can use an endpoint that can have the format as soap11